# Remote Desktop client access license

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, license, windows-server-2012

This is regarding remote access licensing in server 2012. 
Consider I have 10 device based CAL. Is it possible to activate CAL on three different servers so that 10 different user/device can connect to each server?

Comment: Are you asking if RDS CALs are valid for more than one RDS owned by the same company?

Comment: somewhat similar
However, In my case I have 10 per device license and three servers. I have two point of view 1- Total 10 devices can connect to these three servers. like 4 to first server 3 to other then only three to the last server. 2- I can use these 10 licenses on each server and incorporate 10 devices on each server.

Answer (score 0):

Your RDS Servers must communicate with an RDS License Server.  You install your RDS CALs on that license Server.  Then all those devices can connect to any of the RDS servers that use that one license server.